# python - adding each digit that is greater than 4

Tags: python, for-loop

Given an integer. for each individual digit that is greater than 4, i need to add it to all the next digits that greater than 4.
For example: a = 4567; the result should be 0 + (5) + (5+6) + (5+6+7) = 34
So far in my code, I was able to get the sum for single digit only. If the integer is greater 10, it will only give the sum of the very first digit. Any idea why this happening?

```
def morethanfour(number):
    num = 0
    num = [int(d) for d in str(number)] #seperate into individual digit  
    total = 0
    for i in range (len(num)):
        if num[i] > 4:
            total = sum(x for x in range(5, num[i]+1)) #adding the sum

    return total


num = 9
print(morethanfour(num))
```

the result when num = 9 is 35 (5+6+7+8+9)
However, when num = 178, it gave me 0

Comment: I do not understand the problem description.  
You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: @StephenRauch: In the grand scheme of things, this is already pretty minimized. They have a single function of a few lines, and an example with what their code gives, and what they expect it to give.

Comment: @BillLynch What I was hoping for was more data....  The statement `all the next digits` is ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> def morethanfour(number):
        return sum(sum(range(5,x+1)) for x in map(int,str(number)) if x>4)

>>> morethanfour(9)
35
>>> morethanfour(4567)
34
>>> morethanfour(178)
44
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> sum(sum(num[j] for j in range(0, i+1) if num[j] > 4) for i in range(len(num)))
34
```

Comment: Hmm, I missed the scope of `num`. Only saw the `num` variable _outside_ the function; and this answer is using the one _inside_ the function. Sorry. But can't retract the vote as 15+ minutes passed. Thanks for the clarification.